# How can I display an image sequence as a volume in ParaView?

Tags: vtk, paraview

As a replacement for ImageJ's 3D-Viewer I'm trying to display a sequence of microscopic images as a volume in ParaView 5.4.1. I tried following [this guide](http://wiki.rac.manchester.ac.uk/community/ParaView/Tips/LoadImageStack) which suggests to save the image sequence as a `.raw` file with ImageJ, open that in ParaView and manually enter the image dimensions. I'm not seeing the fields where I could enter image dimensions in ParaView though, and clicking "Apply" after loading the `.raw` file does nothing. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the file, you are probably getting a dialog box titled "Open Data With..." and given a list of file formats that potentially match the file. Make sure you select "Raw (binary) Files". That is the one that reads images as a raw binary array of data and gives you lots of options to specify the size of the array (including reading the files as a 3D stack).

***Don't*** use the one that says "RAW Files". That is a different mesh format used by some CAD programs.